# Since setState is asynchronous, is it executed via callback queue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and was learnig how setState works behind the scenes. Thus I would like to ask some questions on it. Firstly, is setState always asynchronous? if not in what general situations it is synchronous. Secondly, how asynchrony happens in setState is it executed via web api and then callback queue? Guys if something is not clear please let me know. I just really need your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. it's always asynchronous and never synchronous. 
common mistakes by developers is something like this

```
 handleEvent(newValue) {
   this.setState({ value: newValue }, () => {
      // you can get the updated state here
      console.log(this.state.value)
   })
   this.doSomething(newValue)
 }

 doSomething(newValue) {
   // this.state.value is still the old value
   if (this.state.value === newValue) {
      // blabla
   }
 }
```

And you can't determine how much time it will take for the state to update.

Comment: Jasper thank you for your answer, is setState executed via web api and than is put into callback queue?

Comment: yes. as you see in the example it's an asynchronous function that has a callback function that will be executed after completion

Comment: ok Jasper, imagine we have function Reset which is executed on button click. Here is just simplified function code: Reset(){this.setState({count:0})} this.setState({count:this.state.count+1}) The question is Are both this.setState functions inside Reset function executed asynchronously?

Comment: if you have multiple setState in a single function, react batches all your setState in a single asynchronous update as you will notice. it will rerender once

Answer (score 2):

React setState is not always asynchronous, it depends upon how state change was triggered.

1) Synchronous - If the action is outside of Reactjs world or if the state change was triggered by **timer** or **user induced** **event handler**, then reactjs can't batch updates and has to mutate the state immediately.

2) Asynchronous
If the state change is triggered by onClick, then Reactjs can batch updates to the state for performance gains.

Working [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-frost-ylnq2)

and

[Reference post](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2893-setstate-state-mutation-operation-may-be-synchronous-in-reactjs.htm)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    // const intervalId = setInterval(this.updateState, 5000);
    // this.setState({intervalId: intervalId});
    this.counter.addEventListener("mousedown", this.updateState);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.counter.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.updateState);
    // clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
  }
  updateState = event => {
    console.log("= = = = = = = = = = = =");
    console.log("EVENT:", event ? event.type : "timer");
    console.log("Pre-setState:", this.state.counter);
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });
    console.log("Post-setState:", this.state.counter);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <span onClick={this.updateState} ref={elem => (this.counter = elem)}>
          Counter at {this.state.counter}
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

> console logs

```
    = = = = = = = = = = = =
    EVENT: mousedown 
    Pre-setState: 
    0
    Post-setState: 
    1
    = = = = = = = = = = = = 
    EVENT: click 
    Pre-setState: 
    1
    Post-setState: 
    1
```

As you can see in console logs, `mousedown` event state change is immediately reflected but `onClick` change is asynchronous or better said batched.

So its better we assume the state change will be asynchronous and use callback handler to avoid bugs.
And off-course anything inside callback will go through event loop in javascript.

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: thank you for your great answer, please can you explain what you meant by "outside of Reactjs world or if the state change was triggered by timer or user induced event handler" Thank you

Comment: If you use attach `event handler` or use `setTimeout` function inside your code, they are outside the context of Reactjs, so Reactjs can't batch updates as you can see in the example given in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. it's asynchronous. And in Javascript asynchronous actions are handled using `event loop`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: hi Roopak, thank you for your answer, I have a function called Reset() which is executed when user clicks on button. So, the code is like this: Reset(){this.setState({count:0}) this.setState({count:this.setState.count+1})} I understood that both setStates are batched and executed asynchronously. Initial state of count is 5 but why if I click the button I get 6 instead of 1?

Comment: Try using setState as a callback function.  this.setState(function(prevState, props){
      return {count: prevState.count + 1}
   })

Comment: Roopak thank you for your reply, ok it works but why the previous code did not work. Please can you briefly explain?:) Just let me explain why I think my previous code should work. Since both setStates are executed via event loop then count is firstly equalized to 0 and then 1 is added to it. Is that right?:)

Comment: So in the first case you are trying to update the state value of counter using its previous value. But unfortunately  this value of counter has not been updated yet so react takes the initial value of counter and adds 1 to it. In the second case(working scenario) we are telling react that treat this in a special way make my setState work synchronously.